# Ubuntu some keys are not working

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

Following are system details,
Kernet-Release: 4.15.0-29-generic
Kernet-Release: #31~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 18 08:54:04 UTC 2018

I am using HP 630 laptop. Every key was working fine until now, however, due to some changes following keys are not working,

- Delete
- Print Screen
- Equal To key

Let me know if further information is needed.